# Mysql auto-increment by customer

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a table `Invoices` which have some some fields like `InvoiceId`, `Customer`, `Number`
I want the field `Number` to be auto-increment but per `customer` 
this is an exemple of what it would look like 
For exemple

```
InvoiceId| Customer| Number
:------- | ------: | :----:
258      | A       | 1
2568     | B       | 1
85475    | B       | 2
63       | B       | 3
64       | A       | 2
65       | B       | 4
67       | C       | 1
```

Comment: Interesting question. What you have tried so far? Where do you get stuck at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be possible [only using MyISAM storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> **MyISAM Notes**
>
> For MyISAM tables, **you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index**. In this case, **the generated value
>   for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as
>   MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix**. This is
>   useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>     grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
>     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
>
> INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
>     ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
>     ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
>     ('bird','ostrich');
>
> SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
> ```
>
> Which returns:
>
> ```
> +--------+----+---------+
> | grp    | id | name    |
> +--------+----+---------+
> | fish   |  1 | lax     |
> | mammal |  1 | dog     |
> | mammal |  2 | cat     |
> | mammal |  3 | whale   |
> | bird   |  1 | penguin |
> | bird   |  2 | ostrich |
> +--------+----+---------+
> ```
>
> In this case (when the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of a
>   multiple-column index), AUTO_INCREMENT values are reused if you delete
>   the row with the biggest AUTO_INCREMENT value in any group. This
>   happens even for MyISAM tables, for which AUTO_INCREMENT values
>   normally are not reused.

emphasis mine.

So, if you are using a different storage engine, you'll need to manually generate your sequence ID.

Comment: indeed, InnoDB can only have one auto-incremented and it must be a primary-key. But there must be a way to do a insert with a max()+1 somewhere?

Comment: This said i don't know how innoDB will handle an auto-increment (int) + another datatype, both as primary key

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE number number INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

if CHANGE won't work then try MODIFY

Comment: My table storage is MyISAM, and in phpmyadmin it still giving me error :#1075-Incorrecr table definistion ; there can be only one auto cullumn and it musr be defined as key